# Minecraft: How can I create a function that prevents players from swimming upstream?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a custom map in Minecraft and came across an idea involving running water as an obstacle. I was wondering if there was a way to create running water that would beat and push the player in the direction of flow as though they were being dragged downstream like white water rapids.

A /tp command that executes if the player is in a flowing water block might do it, but I was wondering if there was anything smoother and more reliable.

Comment: Well, one thing that doesn't work is levitation with a level between 128 and 255. That usually makes players glide down smoothly, but levitation has no effect in water.

Comment: @Fabian Good point, though I was more concerned with preventing players from crossing a fast-flowing stream.

Comment: Another thing that doesn't work is abusing [MC-71781](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-71781). Even with poison 127, wither 127 and while starving, you can still swim up, just very slowly.

Comment: Another thing that doesn't work is giving the player a motion tag, because you can't edit player's NBT data. You could create a different entity with a motion tag and then teleport the player to it, but it would still just be teleportation. You might be able to push the player down with other entities, but I don't know how well that works.

Comment: Nope, entity collision only works sideways.

Comment: Would it be ok if the player just fell as if there was no water at all? Then you might be able to make it appear as if there was water there while it's in reality just an entity model that looks like water.

Comment: As I said before, I'm really only trying to prevent players from crossing a stream horizontally. Your entity collision idea might actually provide a clue to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha! I did it! I created an invisible and silent ghast with the tag "fast_water" using this command:

```
/summon ghast ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1,Silent:1,Invulnerable:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:1000000,ShowParticles:0b}],Tags:["fast_water"]}
```

And I used a series of repeating command blocks to detect if a player was standing in any height of flowing water, then if the conditions were met, teleported the invisible ghast a small space ahead of the player, so that the collision box would force the player downstream! Huzzah!

I only needed this for one direction of flowing water, so I don't need to optimize it for every direction.

Comment: If you have multiple players, you may want a smaller entity as the pusher (so it doesn't hit the other players).  Potentially a stack of 3-10 chickens (for push force tuning)?